# How get team site groupId property from a SPFX webpart with pnp/js

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

I create a webpart with SPFX and it is deployed in a team site. I need get the team site groupId property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the `groupId` with the following code:

```
sp.web.select("AllProperties").expand("AllProperties").get().then(w => {
    console.log(w.AllProperties.RelatedGroupId);
});
```